# Anyone using the Telinga parabolic mic?

Tags: field, field-recording, microphone

Difficult to test this, so whats your experience with it?
Does the mic sound good and is it quiet, or is it better to use a MKH mic with the telinga parabol? Also, I dont see the reason for a stereo mic in this setup. I might have missed something, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Tim Prebble's](https://sound.stackexchange.com/users/49/tim-prebble) blog at http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/
He uses one and has some blog posts and examples.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, yeah i read that and thats the reason why i started to think about the universal kit with a MKH mic. Still curious about the stereo dat mic they make though. Anyone tested them?

Comment: It's not something i've tried but interested as well. Looks like quite a cool thing.